# Retrieving values from another script via get/set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a little bit of a problem with my code. I have 2 C# scripts for a game I am creating in Unity: one is called `characterstats.cs`, and the other is `enemycontroller.cs`.

I have declared a public variable which is set to a getter and setter in the `characterstats.cs` script:

```
public int deathTriggerSet { get; set; }
```

In that script, I have set the `deathTriggerSet` value to 2

```
if (currentHealth <= 0)
{
    _animator.SetTrigger("DeathTrigger");
    currentHealth = 0;
    GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
    _animator.SetInteger("Death",2);
    _animator.SetBool("Fire",false);
        deathTriggerSet = 2;
    return;
}
```

Now in `enemycontroller.cs` script, i have the following:

```
if (inRange && aC == attackCooldown && deathTriggerSet!=2)
{
    Fire();
    aC = 0f;
}
```

However I get the following error

> error CS0103: The name `deathTriggerSet' does not exist in the current context

I dont want to create a new instance, so I am a little stuck how do I retrieve this value using the getter/setter methodology, unless there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: You need to reference some copy of "characterstats", deathTriggerSet doesn't exist in enemycontroller at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make it static if you don't want to make instances

```
public static int deathTriggerSet { get; set; }
```

then

```
if (inRange && aC == attackCooldown && CharacterStats.deathTriggerSet!=2)
{
    Fire();
    aC = 0f;
}
```